# POST method, echo more than 1 checkbox output

Tags: php, html, checkbox, echo

first of all I've been googling about this and found that I need to insert array box inside the checkbox name. I did that but it returned an error. May I knew what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Here's the code that I manage to echo only 1 value although both checkbox are been checked. (Before adding "[]")

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
    <p>If yes, which type of disposable contact lens have you worn before?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens"  value="Monthly"/> Monthly<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens"  value="Daily Disposables"/> Daily Disposables<br>
</div>
</form>

if(empty($_POST["disposable_lens"]))
{
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Disposable_lens is required</label></p>';
}
else
{
    $disposable_lens = clean_text($_POST["disposable_lens"]);
    echo $disposable_lens."</br>";
}
```

This is the code after I inserted the "[]" and used foreach statement

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p>If yes, which type of disposable contact lens have you worn before?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens[]"  value="Monthly"/> Monthly<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens[]"  value="Daily Disposables"/> Daily Disposables<br>
</div>

    if(empty($_POST["disposable_lens"]))
{
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Disposable_lens is required</label></p>';
}
else
{
    foreach($_POST['disposable_lens'] as $disposable_lens){
        echo $disposable_lens."</br>";
}
```

I got this error when I go to index.php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\send_mail\index.php on line 216

And I checked on line 216, there are no any word, just got one ~ (in red) and I cant delete it. This is the image screenshot I took.

[image]

Comment: seems you are missing a semi colon somewhere

Comment: You are missing a } at the very bottom of your code for the else statement.

Comment: When you added the `foreach` loop you forgot to add the matching `}` so your braces don't match any more.

Comment: Thanx a lot guys. So silly of me to not see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment you are missing a } at the end of your code for the else statement.  Also, I do not see where you are setting your php tags when you transition from html to php.  This is how your code should look:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p>If yes, which type of disposable contact lens have you worn before?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens[]"  value="Monthly"/> Monthly<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens[]"  value="Daily Disposables"/> Daily Disposables<br>
</div>

<?php

    if(empty($_POST["disposable_lens"])){

    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Disposable_lens is required</label></p>';

    }else{

      foreach($_POST['disposable_lens'] as $disposable_lens){

        echo $disposable_lens."</br>";

      }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. So silly of me to not see that. btw, yeah I got the php tag somewhere, just not put it in here.

Comment: Ive stared at code for hours over stupid stuff like this..  Glad you got it figured out.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `}` after the `foreach`.

Change :

```
 if(empty($_POST["disposable_lens"]))
{
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Disposable_lens is required</label></p>';
}
else
{
    foreach($_POST['disposable_lens'] as $disposable_lens){
        echo $disposable_lens."</br>";
}
```

To :

```
    if(empty($_POST["disposable_lens"]))
{
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Disposable_lens is required</label></p>';
}
else
{
    foreach($_POST['disposable_lens'] as $disposable_lens){
        echo $disposable_lens."</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. So silly of me to not see that.